# Mercurial status command for single file

Tags: c#, mercurial, status

I am using [Mercurial.NET](https://mercurialnet.codeplex.com) and I need to get the status of one or more files (commited, modified, etc).

How can I use Mercurial.NET or at least Mercurial to do this?

Basically, I need to provide the paths of the desired files to the status command somehow.

I don't want to get a list of all the files and their status and filter them based on their path.

I see that TortoiseHG does this, but I can't figure out how to do this in cmd-line or from within Mercurial.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now that :

`hg status <path_to_file_in_the_repo>`

seems to do what I want.
And in Mercurial.NET it is:

```
        var repo = new Repository(path);
        var s = new StatusCommand();
        s = s.WithInclude(FileStatusIncludes.Modified)
            .WithAdditionalArgument("\"" + file + "\"")
            .WithTimeout(1000);
        s.Validate();
        var ret = repo.Status(s);
```